# Why cannot secure copy any more after installed io.js

Tags: node.js, macos, scp, io.js

After installed io.js by nvm and switched to it on this CentOS linux box, I switched over to a Mac and tired to secure copy a file to it.

After the usual command "**scp file root@ip:/folder**" and typed in password, 
instead of the usual progress , I got

```
"Now running io.js v1.6.3"
```

That is actually correct version number that I just installed on the linux box. But what has happened? Does io.js change the meaning of "secure copy" or something?

I tried to turn back to the old node.js using nvm, issue persisted. At the end, out of means, I completely remove nvm from which I installed io.js, finally then scp works again.

Anyone can explain what that was all about? I am very curious.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  My solution was to remove "nvm use *node-version*" from the ~/.bashrc file, and create ~/.nvmrc to contain the default *node-version*.

Comment: Is this a bug or normal behavior. I was kinda looking for the cause of it. Thanks for answering anyways.

Comment: Add some more echo statements to .bashrc and see if they show up when you scp a file, or ssh in.